# How to walk through nested JSON object and update values in python?

Tags: python, json, recursion

I have a JSON object that I want to walk through and check/update all of the string leaf nodes. I don't know the depth of the JSON (it is a representation of a nested user interface) so I want to walk through the JSON object recursively.

The code below demonstrates what I want to try and do and I've tried a few different attempts (https://nvie.com/posts/modifying-deeply-nested-structures/) but I can't seem to get it right. I either get a 'dictionary changed size during iteration' or a 'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not tuple' error.

```
import json

# function for iterating through every JSON item
def walk(obj, parent_first=True):

    # Top down?
    if parent_first:
        yield (), obj

    # For nested objects, the key is the path component.
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        children = obj.items()

    # For nested lists, the position is the path component.
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
        children = enumerate(obj)

    # Scalar values have no children.
    else:
        children = []

    # Recurse into children
    for key, value in children:
        for child_path, child in walk(value, parent_first):
            yield (key,) + child_path, child

    # Bottom up?
    if not parent_first:
        yield (), obj

def Test():
  
  response = """
  {
      "Name":"Mixed Listbox",
      "Type":"ListBox",
      "Visible?":true,
      "Enabled State":"Enabled",
      "Value":0,
      "All Items":[
        "Non-Unicode",
        "FFFE55006E00690063006F0064006500"
      ]
  }
  """
  
  response = json.loads(response)

  # iterate through each item in the JSON object and update the string items
  for path, value in walk(response):
    # if the JSON item is a string
    if isinstance(value,str):
      # update the string value
      response[path] = 'string: ' + value
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 56, in <module> File "<string>", line 50, in Test   File "<string>", line 23, in walk RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

**Expected Output**

```
  response = """
  {
      "Name":"string: Mixed Listbox",
      "Type":"string: ListBox",
      "Visible?":true,
      "Enabled State":"string: Enabled",
      "Value":0,
      "All Items":[
        "string: Non-Unicode",
        "string: FFFE55006E00690063006F0064006500"
      ]
  }
  """
```

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of your errors?

Comment: Yes - I've now added it to the post.

Comment: The way you have posted it I can't see what actual line the error is on

Comment: I separated the code out and was running it through an online python interpreter so that it was as simple/straightforward example as possible. https://onlinegdb.com/Bk4x8rjrO

Comment: You can't add a key to a dictionary while you are iterating over it.

Comment: That's just it, I'm not trying to add a key - I'm trying to update the string value to prepend a string to it (as mentioned in the first sentence of my post). I tried another method where I started with a new, empty object but that didn't work either.

Comment: Well, that is very  much not what you are doing. You can't use the `[]` with a path

Comment: Can you perhaps help me then by showing me a way to do what I want? The intention of my code is to recursively walk through the JSON object and update the values that match the criteria

Comment: The main problem the walk function which returns only a path which is not useful. Modify it to return the actual dictionary you want to edit

Answer (score 0):

This was the final solution that I implemented, it didn't use a generic 'walk' function but it does recurse through the JSON object and updates any string items. The bit I was missing was to return and update the object rather than trying to return the path and then update it.

```
  # converts unicode hex strings into strings for known types in the return data
  def handleUnicode(self,response):
     
    def decode_dict(obj):
    
      # if dict, children are items
      if isinstance(obj,dict):
        children = obj.items()
    
      # if list/tuple, enumerate items    
      elif isinstance(obj,(list,tuple)):
        children = enumerate(obj)
    
      # scalar values have no children  
      else:
        children = []
        # if the obj is a string, decode it
        if isinstance(obj,str):
            obj = self.decodeBomHexString(obj)
      
      # iterate through the children (recursively)    
      for key,value in children:
        obj[key] = decode_dict(value)
      
      return obj    
      
    response = decode_dict(response)
    
    return response
```